# recordar usuario y clave en navegador

Tags: php

una pregunta estoy tratando de que cuando se logue y seleciono en el checbox se quede grabado en el formulario este es el codigo que utilizo

```
if(isset($_POST['recordarme']) && !empty($_POST['recordarme'])){
$dominio = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
setcookie("recordarme", $_POST['recordarme'], time()+3600, "/" , $dominio);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bueno Hay una opción en todos los formularios de acceso a nuestras cuentas de correo, foros, blogs, etc. muy famosa por la función que ofrece. Recordar usuario y contraseña en este ordenador es algo que mucha gente utiliza para evitar tener que introducir sus credenciales siempre que acceda a una página web desde su ordenador.

Si bien puede ser un problema importante de seguridad ante una pérdida o robo del equipo, en todos los formularios de acceso podremos ver dicha función.

**¿Qué es una Cookie?**

Para que la página web reconozca siempre nuestro usuario y contraseña en un sitio web, usa las cookies. Para quien no lo sepa, las cookies son archivos creados por las páginas web en los que almacena determinada información del visitante, ya sean preferencias o información de su perfil.

**Creando un sistema de cookies
**

Para crear un sistema que reconozca al usuario incluso al cerrar el navegador y volver a abrirlo vamos a usar un fichero con el formulario y la comprobación de cookies, y otro de autenticación.

En este ejercicio, para hacerlo más sencillo y claro, no me voy a centrar ni en la creación de la sesión de usuario ni en la securización de la identificación.

La tabla a parte de los datos básicos del usuario llevará un campo llamado cookie donde almacenaremos un valor aleatorio para comprobar la cookie del usuario.

En el fichero index.php, en el formulario pondremos los campos de usuario, contraseña y también el check de recordar contraseña.

lo que tu necesitas es esto:

```html
if(isset($_COOKIE['id_user']) && isset($_COOKIE['marca'])){
 if($_COOKIE['id_user']!="" || $_COOKIE['marca']!=""){
  $sql_c = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users 
     WHERE id_user='".$_COOKIE["id_user"]."' 
     AND cookie='".$_COOKIE["marca"]."'
     AND cookie<>'';");
 }
 if(mysql_num_rows($sql_c)){
  $row_c = mysql_fetch_array($sql_c);
  echo "El usuario ".$row_c['username']." se ha identificado correctamente.";
  $user_cookie = mysql_fetch_array($sql_c);
 }
}
```

te recomendiendo que veas el tutorial completo en la pagina web del autor :
[Autor](http://soyautodidacta.com/2013/07/recordar-usuario-y-contrasena-php-cookies/)

igualmente te recomiendo que leas sobre : Cookies en el sitio oficial de php :   [documentacion de php](http://php.net/manual/es/features.cookies.php)

pero igualmente te recomiendo usar la version 5 de PHP : 
[PHP 5](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)

igualmente te invito a que veas este tutorial que tiene el mismo codigo preo usando Class, te lo dejo a lo ultimo porque en tu codigo no se ve que uses OOP , pero igualmente te recomiendo que uses OOP en php este es el link: 
[link](http://www.bogotobogo.com/php/php15_cookies_sessions.php)

antes de nada te sugiero que veas esta pregunta en stackoverflow donde hablan acerca de Cookies y su seguridad:[la pregunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015860/cookies-security)
Espero que te sirva.